# To find actors who were never unemployed for more than 3 years in a stretch

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm suppose to find the actors that were never unemployed for more than 3 years at a stretch. (Assume that the actors remain unemployed between two consecutive movies).

The M_cast represents the actors and person table has the name of the actor and the movie table has the year column.

```
SQL code:

SELECT a.Name, c.year
FROM Person a
Inner Join M_cast b
ON a.PID = b.PID
Inner Join Movie c
ON c.MID = b.MID
```

This would give us all the actor name and the various years they worked , however, I'm not sure how to check if the an actor worked for 3 years in a row or not. Would appreciate your insights on this. If a similar question was asked anywhere else, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: So can you see that you're effectively looking for all actors missing from a certain query

Comment: if you don't have mysql 8 You have to loop through all all Sorted byanme and year  results and check the years of every actor. This you can do in a stored procedure or in php javasript and so on

Answer (score 0):

So you've got the Actors, Movies (Work), and the Year for each of the Movies. My approach to this would be to use the `LEAD()` function to add a new column `next_year`.

### A bit of background on the function:

> LEAD() is a window function that provides access to a row at a specified physical offset which follows the current row.
>
> For example, by using the LEAD() function, from the current row, you can access data of the next row, or the row after the next row, and so on.
>
> The LEAD() function can be very useful for comparing the value of the current row with the value of the following row.
>
> The following shows the syntax of the LEAD() function:

```
LEAD(return_value ,offset [,default])
OVER (
    [PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ]
    ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...
)
```

Example use:

```
SELECT *
, LEAD(year, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY year ASC) AS next_year
FROM (yourJoinedTable)
```

Using `(next_year - year) AS gap` you can create a column of gaps between movies (years unemployed). Finally, find the `MAX(gap)` for each actor and filter those actors out which have a `MAX(gap)` of ≤ 3. This should leave you with only actors that have no more than 3 years between movies.

Hope this helps!